# Round the number to its nearest base 10 number

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to get the nearest base 10 number (ex. 10, 100, 1000) called `new_n` of the input `n`. For example, `99` gets `100` (not `10`), `551` gets `1000` (not `100`).

What I try is using `np.log10` to extract the power of the input number `n` and use it to power `10`

```
import numpy as np

n = 0.09
new_n = 10**(int(round(np.log10(n))))
print new_n

n = 35
new_n = 10**(int(round(np.log10(n))))
print new_n

n = 999
new_n = 10**(int(round(np.log10(n))))
print new_n

n = 4655
new_n = 10**(int(round(np.log10(n))))
print new_n

> 0.1
> 100
> 1000
> 10000
```

The problem is the number such as `35` its `np.log10(n)` (which I expect to use as power) is `1.544068` and its rounding is `2`. So the result is `100`instead of `10`. Or the result of `4655` is `10000`. How to round the number to the nearest base 10 number?

Comment: try using `math.floor` instead of round.

Comment: @DeepakSingh `math.floor` with always round down, even for `n=999`.

Comment: What is your definition of "nearest"?

Comment: @Craig Like 499 should get 100 because 499 is closer to 100 than 1000 for the number base 10. And 799 should get 1000.

Comment: @unutbu Oh that's true! So sorry. Then 501 should get 100. Let me fix and try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check back in the linear space (with a possible correction) after obtaining the exponent:

```
n = np.array([0.09,35,549,551,999,4655])
e = np.log10(n).round()
#array([-1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.])
```

So, is the number closer to the "rounded" answer or to the previous degree of 10?

```
new_n = np.where(10**e - n <= n - 10**(e - 1), 10**e, 10**(e - 1))
#array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+01,   1.00000000e+02,
#         1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+03])
```

Comment: The number should be close to its round of degree of 10. Like 499 should get 100 but 501 should get 1000.

Comment: @jan 501 is closer to 100 (401) than to 1000 (499). What is your precise definition of closeness?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the midpoint. Everything less than 550 should get 100. More than 550 gets 1000. 550 can be any.

Comment: My code is doing just that. I added 549 and 551 for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by scaling your numbers before taking the logs. Multiply each value by `sqrt(10) / 5.5` and you should get the results you want:

```
n = np.array([0.09,35,549,551,999,4655]) # borrowed test values from @DYZ
multiplier = np.sqrt(10) / 5.5
results = 10**np.log10(multiplier * n).round()
# array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+01,   1.00000000e+02,
#          1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+03,   1.00000000e+03])
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Do you mind explain why multiplier is `np.sqrt(10) / 5.5`? (Just note for others this method round down the midpoint why DYZ's one is round up. I am ok with both btw)

Comment: The multiplier I used transforms the midpoint you want (e.g. `5.5`, `55`, `550`) to the equivalent midpoint on a log scale (`10**0.5`, `10**1.5`, `10**2.5`). I suspect the rounding direction for the exact midpoint values comes down to floating point rounding error. Writing the equation in a slightly different way might make it round the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
import np
new_n = 10**(np.floor(np.log10(n)-np.log10(0.5)))
```